# Parsing/binding JSon file into Table using Angular

Tags: angularjs, json, parsing, html-table

How can I bind Place And Activity under Json? I do parse Event and AccountShop using table and it runs. I think its because of the delimiter in Place and Activiy? Can anyone help or has a suggestion here or advice to take me out of the code.

table.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myTable">
<head>
    <title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myTable=angular.module('myTable',[]);
    myTable.controller('tableCtrl',function($scope,$http){
        $http.get("Table.json").success(function(response){
        $scope.members=response.events;


});

    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    table, th, td{
        border: 2px sol grey;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        padding: 4px;
        font-family: arial;

    }

    table tr:nth-child(odd){
        background-color:   #00BFFF;

    }
    table tr:nth-child(even){
        background-color: #808080;
    }

</style>


</head>




<body ng-controller="tableCtrl">
<table border="1">
    <tr>
    <th>Event</th>
    <th>Account Shop</th>
    <th>Place</th>
    <th>Activity</th>
    </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="member in members">
        <td>{{member.Event.id}}<br>
        {{member.Event.account_id}}<br>
        {{member.Event.shop_id}}<br>


        <td ng-repeat="member in members">
        {{member.AccountShop.id}}<br>
        {{member.AccountShop.name}}<br>
        {{member.AccountShop.short_code}}<br>
        </td>

        <tr ng-repeat="member in members">
        {{member.Place.id}}
        {{member.Place.name}}
        {{member.Place.lk_country_code}}




</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Table.json

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "Event": {
                "id": "59",
                "account_id": "12",
                "shop_id": "12",

            },
            "AccountShop": {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Sample",
                "short_code": "SampleL"
            },
            "Places": [
                {
                    "id": "537",
                    "name": "Sample",
                    "lk_country_code": "MY"
                }
            ],
            "Activities": [
                {
                    "id": "4011",
                    "short_description": "Sample\r\n"
                },
                {
                    "id": "106",
                    "short_description": "Sample\r\n \r\n"
                },
                {
                    "id": "1027",
                    "short_description": "Sample\r\n"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: do you control the data structure from back end? If so structure would be better optimized by moving properties like `Event` inside each item and make a flat array of objects ... use a common property like `type:'Event'`

Comment: can you try to run it pls :) , it ruined me around like, i play with the codes 3 hours ago solving dis lol, and i search for other codes . i think the problem is on the html file ,

Comment: put this code into a demo in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue). Will modify it a bit there if needed

Comment: @Jerald, do you want display grid with inline Grid(rows expanding grid)??

Comment: @Vijay yeah , similar like that :) rows expanding grid

Comment: @Jerald,  i have a sample for Row expanding grid try its,
http://jsfiddle.net/Pixic/6Texj/ this is may be hep to you

Comment: @Vijay tnx so much i really appreciated it ,  !

Comment: @Jerald, this thanks goes to Dr.Abdul Kalam.

Comment: @Vijay hi vija , would like to ask if why i cant parse the  Place in my table using Json , do you think it on because of the parameter? i only parse Event and AccountShop ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <tr ng-repeat="member in members">
    <td>{{member.Event.id}}</td>
    <td>{{member.Event.account_id}}
    <td>{{member.Event.ishop_id}}
   </td><td>{{member.AccountShop.id}}
   </td> </tr>
```

You don't need to iterate through Event, Account, Place , because they are single entities. Instead of this iterate over members. So you can get Event and it's own properties, AccountShop and it's properties and etc...

Comment: this really isn't an answer and is more of a comment. With some extra explanation and code could be converted to answer

Comment: OmG it worksssss!!!! sir you are awesome! i just try to catch up the above code that you gave and it runs ,,:D ,, tnx so much!!!

Comment: Event and AccountShop are single, Place and Activity are collections, so you get last tem through iteration. Call Place -> Places, Activity -> Activities or you get chaos in mind.

Comment: hi i run this codes and it works , but i tried to parse the Place , but JSon cant bind it , i think it's because of the delimeter '['  on the place , i only bind Event and Account shop

Comment: @ВладимирЛапенков i already changed it but nothings happen, but Event and Accountshop runs in a table , Places and Activities wont ,,