# Binding Json file into Table using Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, json, parsing, binding, html-table

How can I  bind Place And Activity under Json? I do parse Event and AccountShop using table and it runs, I think its because of the delimiter in Place and Activiy? Can anyone help or has a suggestion here or advice to take me out of the code.

table.htm

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myTable">
<head>
    <title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myTable=angular.module('myTable',[]);
    myTable.controller('tableCtrl',function($scope,$http){
        $http.get("Table.json").success(function(response){
        $scope.members=response.events;


});

    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    table, th, td{
        border: 2px sol grey;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        padding: 4px;
        font-family: arial;

    }

    table tr:nth-child(odd){
        background-color:   #00BFFF;

    }
    table tr:nth-child(even){
        background-color: #808080;
    }

</style>


</head>




<body ng-controller="tableCtrl">
<table border="1">
    <tr>
    <th>Event</th>
    <th>Account Shop</th>
    <th>Place</th>
    <th>Activity</th>
    </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="member in members">
        <td>{{member.Event.id}}<br>
        {{member.Event.account_id}}<br>
        {{member.Event.shop_id}}<br>


        <td ng-repeat="member in members">
        {{member.AccountShop.id}}<br>
        {{member.AccountShop.name}}<br>
        {{member.AccountShop.short_code}}<br>
        </td>

        <tr ng-repeat="member in members">
        {{member.Place.id}}
        {{member.Place.name}}
        {{member.Place.lk_country_code}}




</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Table.json

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "Event": {
                "id": "59",
                "account_id": "12",
                "shop_id": "12",

            },
            "AccountShop": {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Sample",
                "short_code": "SampleL"
            },
            "Places": [
                {
                    "id": "537",
                    "name": "Sample",
                    "lk_country_code": "MY"
                }
            ],
            "Activities": [
                {
                    "id": "4011",
                    "short_description": "Sample\r\n"
                },
                {
                    "id": "106",
                    "short_description": "Sample\r\n \r\n"
                },
                {
                    "id": "1027",
                    "short_description": "Sample\r\n"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing/binding JSon file into Table using Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31657003/parsing-binding-json-file-into-table-using-angular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look for below solution:
DO not repeat td, instead repeat a Div tag or Span tag inside td:
In below Example I have just hardcoded the json ,in you case json will be retuned from service

http://jsfiddle.net/avaqppn0/1/

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Event</th>
        <th>Account Shop</th>
        <th>Place</th>
        <th>Activity</th>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="member in members">
        <td>{{member.Event.id}}<br>
            {{member.Event.account_id}}<br>
            {{member.Event.shop_id}}<br>


        <td>
            {{member.AccountShop.id}}<br>
            {{member.AccountShop.name}}<br>
            {{member.AccountShop.short_code}}<br>
        </td>

        <td >
            <div ng-repeat="Place in member.Places">
                {{Place.id}}
                {{Place.name}}
                {{Place.lk_country_code}}
            </div>
        </td>
        <td >
            <div ng-repeat="Activity in member.Activities">
                {{Activity.id}}
                {{Activity.short_description}}
            </div>

        </td>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: Plz accept as answer if it solves ur issue..kindly upvote @Jerald

Comment: ok , how was that?sorry im new here. thankyou again  @rahul ,

Comment: @Jerald Click **tick mark** sign near to my answer above, right below the UP and Down arrows

Answer (score 0):

$scope.members=response.events[0];

```
<tr>
    <td ng-repeat="(key,value) in members.Event">
    {{value}} <br>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td ng-repeat="(key,value) in members.AccountShop">
     {{value}} <br>
     </td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="place in members.Places">
    <td >
    {{place.id}} <br>
    {{place.name}} <br>
    {{place.lk_country_code}} <br>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="act members.Activities">
    <td >
    {{act.id}} <br>
    {{act.short_description}} <br>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: hi  , thanks so much for proving the code , but  i try to use your code and the output is repeated ,like for example the value of under event is john , then the output appears like this , John John John John John John John John John John John John  ,