# Binding new Array in a Table using JSonfile

Tags: angularjs, json, parsing, binding, html-table

I would like to ask  how will you show  the "totals array" below the table Event AccountShop, Place and Activity? This code is working but I do have trouble inserting the "total" value in the Json" below the table.

table.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myTable">
<head>
    <title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myTable=angular.module('myTable',[]);
    myTable.controller('tableCtrl',function($scope,$http){
        $http.get("Table.json").success(function(response){
        $scope.members=response.events;


});

    });
</script>

</head>
<body ng-controller="tableCtrl">
<table border="5">
    <tr>
        <th>Event</th>
        <th>Account Shop</th>
        <th>Place</th>
        <th>Activity</th>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="member in members">
    <td>{{member.Event.id}}<br>
    {{member.Event.account_id}}<br>
    {{member.Event.shop_id}}<br>
 <td>
     {{member.AccountShop.id}}<br>
     {{member.AccountShop.name}}<br>
     {{member.AccountShop.short_code}}<br>
     </td>
  <div ng-repeat="Place in member.Place">
      {{Place.id}}<br>
      {{Place.name}}<br>
      {{Place.lk_country_code}}<br>
      </div>
      </td>
 <td>
      <div ng-repeat="Activity in member.Activity">
      {{Activity.id}}<br>
      {{Activity.short_description}}
      </div>

      </td>
      </tr>

      <th>Total</th>

      <td>
      <div ng-repeat="total members.totals">

      {{totals.totals.page}}
      {{totals.current}}
      {{totals.count}}
      {{totals.prevPage}}
      {{totals.nextPage}}
           {{totals.pageCount}}
            {{totals.order}}
             {{totals.limit}}
              {{totals.options}}
               {{totals.paramType}}

 </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Table.json

```
    {
    "events": [
        {
            "Event": {
                "id": "59",
                "account_id": "1",
                "shop_id": "1",

            },
            "AccountShop": {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Gill Divers Pte Ltd",
                "short_code": "GILL"
            },
            "Place": [
                {
                    "id": "537",
                    "name": "Pulau Dayang",
                    "lk_country_code": "MY"
                }
            ],
            "Activity": [
                {
                    "id": "4011",
                    "short_description": "sample\r\n"
                },
                {
                    "id": "106",
                    "short_description": "sample\r\n \r\n"
                },
                {
                    "id": "1027",
                    "short_description": "sample\r\n"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "totals": [],
    "paging": {
        "page": 1,
        "current": 50,
        "count": 3621,
        "prevPage": false,
        "nextPage": true,
        "pageCount": 73,
        "order": [],
        "limit": 50,
        "options": [],
        "paramType": "querystring"
    }
}
```

Comment: could you make it simplified here http://plnkr.co/edit/b2WlEd9uxfkw7kJh4InQ?p=preview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing/binding JSon file into Table using Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31657003/parsing-binding-json-file-into-table-using-angular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `in` in your ng-repeat. Try:

```
<div ng-repeat="total in members.totals">
```

And your totals array is empty:

```
"totals": []
```

But I think your real problem is that your trying to access the wrong property and the right property isn't even available on `$scope.members`

```
myTable.controller('tableCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $http.get("Table.json").success(function(response) {
    debugger
    $scope.members = response.events;
    // you need the paging property which isn't in the events array
    $scope.totals = response.paging;

  });

});
```

Comment: yup i tried that too , but nothings happen ,tnx  @matt

Comment: nope , i tried it , but nothings happen , , do i need to put it on the other table, or it can be in the same table, maybe the problem is on the allignment of my html table ,

Comment: am going to check it again , tnx :)

Comment: thankyou @matt the code runs ,  i just dont have a call function for the total in the scope " $scope.totals = response.paging; "